# Configuration of aurelia-validation

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to configure Aurelia Validation (release 0.2.6) to get all of the validation messages appended to `<input>` element instead of label.

My main.js looks like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .developmentLogging()
  .plugin('aurelia-validation', (config) => { config.useLocale('de-DE').useViewStrategy(ValidateCustomAttributeViewStrategy.TWBootstrapAppendToInput); });

aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('app', document.body));
}
```

I alway get the following error message:

> Unhandled promise rejection ReferenceError: ValidateCustomAttributeViewStrategy is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 
    `import {ValidateCustomAttributeViewStrategy} from 'aurelia-validation';`
to the top of your file

Comment: Thanks, that works! I figured it would be something simple, but I didn't come up with it.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like [this just recently changed](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/8642558efe83b1ea9d8c5fd6b304905fa52fc995/dist/es6/strategies/twbootstrap-view-strategy.js#L109). So as of 10/12/2015 this works:

```
import { TWBootstrapViewStrategy } from 'aurelia-validation';
...

export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .plugin('aurelia-validation', (config) => config
           .useViewStrategy(TWBootstrapViewStrategy.AppendToInput))
        ...
}
```

As an aside, the `d.ts` is currently missing the [definitions for the strategies](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/commit/8642558efe83b1ea9d8c5fd6b304905fa52fc995#diff-e62f10b73d9b3336e92eaf4308dca29eR561) so if you're using TypeScript you'll have to cast the strategy to `any`:

```
import { ValidationConfig, TWBootstrapViewStrategy } from 'aurelia-validation';
...

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .plugin('aurelia-validation', (config: ValidationConfig) => config
            .useViewStrategy((<any>TWBootstrapViewStrategy).AppendToInput))
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For aurelia validation version 1.0. It works with creating a custom renderer. See it [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics) on section custom renderers.